# How to toggle text when a specific value in drop-down AND checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, dom

So right now, I have:

```
<tr>
  <td class="label">Status:</td>
  <td> 
  <select name="bookStatus" id="status">
  <option value="-1">- Select -</option>
  <option value="0">- Active -</option>
  <option value="1">- Disabled -</option>
  <option value="2">- Cancelled -</option>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</br>
<div id=outprint style="display:none">
<tr>
  <td class="label">Out of Print?</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="outOfPrint" id="chk"/></td>
</tr>
</div>  



<div id="showthis" style="display:none">
  <tr>
  <td class="label">Remove from ALL QUEUES and Notify?</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="removeAndNotify"/></td>
</tr>
</div>
```

and my script as:

```
$('#status').change(function () {
    var show = $(this).val();
  if (show != "-1") {
    $('#outprint').show();
  }
  else {
   $('#outprint').hide();
   $('#showthis').hide();
  }

    $('#chk').change(function (){
  if (show == "1") {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $('#showthis').show();
     } else {
     $('#showthis').hide();
     }
  }
  else {
    $('#showthis').hide();
  }
  });
});
```

Basically I am looking for the hidden texts to pop up
When the drop-down menu is changed AND when it's set to Disabled
and you check the checkbox, the last checkbox appears.

The problems I am having are:

1) When I click on Disabled and check the checkbox, and then I change the Disabled to another option, the hidden text still pops up.

2) You click on any option other than the default one, then you click on the checkbox first before you change the option from the drop-down menu to Disabled -> the hidden text does not show up.

How would I approach this?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwwlee/up4j39qr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just need to reset the state of your hidden controls to default once you change the options from the dropdown and then iterate through the logic.

```
$('#status').change(function () {
 ResetState();
    var show = $(this).val();
  if (show != "-1") {
    $('#outprint').show();
  }
  else {
   $('#outprint').hide();
   $('#showthis').hide();
  }

    $('#chk').change(function (){
  if (show == "1") {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $('#showthis').show();
     } else {
     $('#showthis').hide();
     }
  }
  else {
    $('#showthis').hide();
  }
  });
});

function ResetState()
{
   $('#outprint').hide();
   $('#showthis').hide();
   $('#chk').prop("checked", false);
}
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/up4j39qr/4/

Comment: It was very hard to explain this , but thank you!  As a beginner with jQuery, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great. Glad to help :). Happy Friday !!

Answer (score 1):

Changes made: Invalid htmls fixed, Improper event bindings fixed.

Your HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Status:</td>
      <td>
        <select name="bookStatus" id="status">
          <option value="-1">- Select -</option>
          <option value="0">- Active -</option>
          <option value="1">- Disabled -</option>
          <option value="2">- Cancelled -</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table id=outprint style="display:none">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Out of Print?</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="outOfPrint" id="chk" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="showthis" style="display:none">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Remove from ALL QUEUES and Notify?</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="removeAndNotify" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var show;
$('#status').change(function() {
  show = $(this).val();
  if (show != "-1") {
    $('#outprint').show();
  } else {
    $('#outprint').hide();
    $('#showthis').hide();
  }
});

$('#chk').change(function() {
  if (show == "1") {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('#showthis').show();
    } else {
      $('#showthis').hide();
    }
  } else {
    $('#showthis').hide();
  }
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/up4j39qr/1/)

Comment: +1. And @CSishard, you should avoid defining one event handler inside another (unless you have a good reason to do so).